# Use controllers to: Manipulate DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a `ng-repeat-end-watch` directive

```
.....
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                scope.$evalAsync(attr.ngRepeatEndWatch);
            }
        }
    }
```

on my markup i have

```
<div ng-repeat="(i, tile) in tiles" class="w3-col tile tile-{{tile.number}}" ng-repeat-end-watch="ctlr.resize()" ng-model="tile">
```

and on my controller I have

```
  rowsColumns = Math.round(Math.sqrt($scope.tiles.length)), widthHeight = $window.screen.availHeight/rowsColumns;
ctlr.resize = function(){

        angular.element('.w3-col').width(widthHeight).height(widthHeight);
      };
```

If in the developer's guide for AngularJS it recommends that you shouldn't use controllers to manipulate DOM elements

What would the recommended way be to apply the above "resize" if its not a good idea to use controllers to manipulate the DOM?

Comment: is there any event listener attached to the Markup ? i am wondering when `resize()` will be called .

Answer (score 0):

Angular is mostly for functionality, not direct DOM manipulation. You probably noticed that you access elements based on their model not id. You don't need any id in an an Angular app which makes it easier if certain html bits change. As long as the model stays the same you can do what you want with the html.

This being said if you do need to access the DOM you can still do it. You could have the code which does that outside of the controller in its own js file for example. Then you can inject it as an Angular service and reuse it in whichever controller you want.

I would try to keep things nicely separated and the controllers very thin. If you code it this way then it's easier to test things as you don't have to worry about controllers anymore. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: quote..."This being said if you do need to access the DOM you can still do it. You could have the code which does that outside of the controller in its own js file for example." 

This seems a bit tricky....looks like more work based on what I want to do and doesn't seem feasible but I will try it. Why a service though?

Comment: if there is a directive involved here , then necessary DOM manipulation can be done inside link function of the directive.

Comment: developing a service/ directive sounds like such an excessive task..... usually in a MVC pattern you would probably do all of this in a View...I guess you are saying that a directive/ service is a View pattern. *shrugs*

Comment: a service gives you a way to inject and reuse a certain bit of code between controllers. it's also a singleton so you could actually have some state in it if you need to. All in all it's a nice way of decoupling code and keeping your controllers light. I like to code this way because most of my work is meant to last for years and I might actually want to change frameworks sometimes. I can take the code from a service, make it a component and chuck it in Angular 2 for example. I do realise not everyone has such a need.

Comment: don't think of Angular as an MVC framework, think of it as an MV* (  whatever ) framework. We're talking about reusing code and separating it as well so testing it becomes easier.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with it is writing your own directive. 
 In fact, directives are one of the most powerful concepts in Angular.js.

Think of it as reusable components: not only for jQuery plugins, but also for any of your (sub) controllers that get used in multiple places. 
It’s kinda like shadow DOM. And the best part is, your controller does not need to know the existence of directives: communications are achieved through scope sharing and $scope events.